# Church Fathers on life beyond the earth?

Tags: church-fathers, science, medieval-church, extra-terrestrial-life

Are there any [church fathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Fathers) or medieval Christian writers who gave their opinion on [extraterrestrial lives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrial_life)?

Comment: Your own links give an answer : _Early Christian writers discussed a "plurality of worlds" as proposed by earlier thinkers such as Democritus; Augustine references Epicurus's idea of innumerable worlds "throughout the boundless immensity of space" (originally expressed in his Letter to Herodotus) in The City of God.[4] In his first-century poem De rerum natura (Book 2:1048–1076), the Epicurean philosopher Lucretius predicted that humanity would find innumerable exoplanets with life-forms similar to, and different from, the ones on Earth, and even other races of man.[citation needed]_.

Answer (score 3):

**Church Fathers on life beyond the earth?**

This is an [exotheology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotheology) topic as it deals with the examination of theological issues as they pertain to extraterrestrial intelligence.

There are [claims](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43250104) that some Church Fathers supported the idea that extraterrestrial life is a possibility. This this is a false statement. It comes from corrupting the meaning and translation of the word [alien](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(law)) which generally should be translated as foreigner and not as an alien from another world. Do not Americans and some other countries calls foreigners in there country aliens! Canada calls them "foreign nationals"!

Wikipedia has this to say:

> Speculation about the possibility of inhabited worlds beyond Earth dates back to antiquity. Early Christian writers discussed the idea of a "plurality of worlds" as proposed by earlier thinkers such as Democritus; Augustine references Epicurus's idea of innumerable worlds "throughout the boundless immensity of space" (originally expressed in his Letter to Herodotus) in The City of God. In his first-century poem De rerum natura (Book 2:1048–1076), the Epicurean philosopher Lucretius predicted that humanity would find innumerable exoplanets with life-forms similar to, and different from, the ones on Earth, and even other races of man. - [Extraterrestrial life](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrial_life)

The Vatican sees no problem with the possibility that extraterrestrial life exists and it remains an open question.